# How to calculate kills/deaths ratio in a computer game?

Tags: php, mysql

I need my computer game to take all kills and deaths from a user's total and then make it so the kills are divided by the deaths, then that total is put at the end. This ratio is known as their kill-death ratio, or "KDR".

```
 <?php
   // Create connection
   $con=mysqli_connect("ipaddress","user","password","minecraft");

   // Check connection
   if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
     echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }
   $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *, `kills`/`deaths` as `KDR` FROM war_kills ``ORDER BY kills DESC");




   echo "<table border='1'>
   <tr>
   <th>Player</th>
   <th>Kills</th>
   <th>Deaths</th>
   <th>KDR</th>
   </tr>";

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['player'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['kills'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['deaths'] . "</td>";
     echo "<td>" . $row['KDR'] . "</td>";

     echo "</tr>";
   }

   echo "</table>";
   ?>
```

We have this up so far: http://gexgaming.com/warstats/index.php

Comment: @Sean that would simply add the two together and not give the ratio. The equation is `KDR = K / D`

Comment: Actually, deaths == 0 may be treated differently, as it would give probably undesired results in both PHP or MySQL.

Comment: Would you add to your question a brief description of what you have so far? The link to your site is okay, but it is a good rule of thumb to write the post as if it was not there. If the question requires a link to make sense, it may be closed, since an external link that breaks would render the question useless.

Answer (score 1):

Change the query from

```
SELECT player, kills, deaths, KDR FROM war_kills ORDER BY kills DESC`
```

to

```
SELECT player, kills, deaths, kills / deaths as KDR FROM war_kills ORDER BY kills DESC`
```

Answer (score 1):

Either modify the SQL query as suggested or do it within the PHP loop:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['player'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['kills'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $row['deaths'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . ($row['kills'] / $row['deaths']) . "</td>"; // <--- this one

 echo "</tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to group your results based on the player name. Also, you need to account for when `deaths = 0`. Try changing your query to -

```
SELECT
    player, 
    SUM(kills) as kills, 
    SUM(deaths) as deaths, 
    CASE WHEN SUM(deaths) = 0 THEN SUM(kills)
         ELSE SUM(kills)/SUM(deaths)
    END as `KDR` 
FROM war_kills 
GROUP BY player
ORDER BY kills DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers I read don't account for the fact that someone might have zero deaths. If they do, you'll get a divide by zero error.

inside your while loop,

```
if ($row['deaths'] == 0)
    $kdr = '-';
else
    $kdr = $row['kills']/$row['deaths'];
```

then change `$row['KDR']` to `$kdr`

Comment: Actually I did on my comment (written before yours), and my version works, as x/0 will return null in MySQL.